# Execute job in Jenkins every X minutes and in a time range

Tags: time, jenkins, cron

I would like to execute a job in Jenkins with a cron every 15 minutes between a time range.

I tried with this:

```
15 8-19 * * 1-5
```

But it execute hourly. I want this:

> Every 15 minutes From 8AM to 7PM and from Monday to Friday.

Answer (score 3):

From the Jenkins' cron syntax:

> - * specifies all valid values
> - M-N specifies a range of values
> - M-N/X or */X steps by intervals of X through the specified range or whole valid range
>
> To allow periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the system, the symbol H (for “hash”) should be used **wherever possible**.

According to the rules above you can use the following:

```
H/15 8-19 * * 1-5
```

Answer (score 1):

If I under Stand Your question all you need is something like below :

`*/15 4,7 * * * /bin/sample >/dev/null 2>&1`

i use [crontab generator Online](http://crontab-generator.org/) to get crontab configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
*/15 8-18 * * 1-5
```

This will give you what you want, but the last execution will be at 18:45.
*/x means 'execute once in a given 'x' minutes/hours/etc